# How to deal with the challenges Allah gives us?

Tags: jannah

After each prayer i'm asking Allah for Janah/heaven. However, my life has gotten very difficult since then. I've gone through many problems and am wondering how to stay positive.

My question is how do you stay positive while going through the challenges? It's incredibly challenging. I'm really tired.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site we are no peer support nor do we offer counselling. For further information take our [tour] and visit our [help].

Comment: @Medi1Saif ok. I thought it was about implementation of Islam but will keep it generic next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to think of it as a challenge/trial. I have gone through some problems too. Remember that you are on Allah's Earth and that Allah knows everything and that Allah knows best.

"Fighting has been enjoined upon you while it is hateful to you. But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not." Surah 2:216

Just remember that Allah knows best and that this world is nothing compared to what Allah can give you. The wealth, women/men and luxuries are nothing.

Comment: "perhaps you hate a thing it is good for you..." This helped. I need to change my perspective.

Comment: In case anyone else has the same question. Read this verse
https://quran.com/2/214-224
It talks about hardships everyone has to go through in their life.